# Vue.js clear bootstrap dialog bound data on launch

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal dialog:

```
<update-dialog id="updateDlg" :items="items" />
```

Which is launched at the click of a button on the main page:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-block"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#updateDlg">
  Update
</button>
```

Is it possible to perform some logic every time the modal is displayed? Like some sort of init actions. I just wanted to clear the previously set values.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bootstrap with Jquery. You can show modal by Javascript code

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-block"
        @click="showModal">
  Update
</button>

methods: {
  showModal() {
    this.items = ... // do some init actions
    $('#updateDlg').modal('show')
  }
}
```

Another solution is listening to show modal event:

```
$('#updateDlg').on('show.bs.modal', (e) => {
  // do something...
})
```

Comment: It would be better to have the child handle this, there are data members in the child which also should be reset. With this method those cannot be reset. Either I need the child component to be recreated, or be able to call an `reset()` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found is to set up an event in the components `mounted`:

```
mounted() {
  $('#updateDlg').on('show.bs.modal', (e) => {
    this.reset(); // reset logic here
  });
}
```